# Javascript string match on first or last name, including partials

Tags: javascript

Say I have a list of users with `firstName` and `lastName` and want to filter those who match either first or last names, or both, or any parts, regardless of whitespace. How would I construct that filter?

The closest I've been able to get is

```
const userString = (user.firstName + user.lastName + user.email).toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g,'');
return userString.includes(filterValue); // where filter value is the thing to test
```

So if we're working with `users = [John Smith, Adam Applebaum, Steve Wright]`, and I type "jo" or "sm" I correctly get "John Smith", but if I type "josm" I would also want "John Smith", but I can't seem to get that to return.

How can I construct a filter or test to include both first and last names, or any combo therein.

@Nina's answer below worked perfect, but I had to modify a bit for my particular use case, my final implementation was;

```
  private _filter(value: string): User[] {
    if (!value || typeof value !== 'string') { return this.users; }
    const regexp = new RegExp([...(value.split(" "))].join('.*'), 'i');
    return this.users.filter(user => {
      const userString = user.firstName + ' ' + user.lastName;
      return regexp.test(userString);
    });
  }
```

Comment: try to `trim` `filtervalue` and i guess it should work

Comment: `includes` search in sequence so it matches `jo` or `so` properly but it will not match `josm` as these characters are not coming continuously in any of your users name,  you need to use regex with with wildcard character `.*`

Comment: Should `josm` also match `Jako Some`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could space each character with a joker and test the string.

```js
function filter(array, string) {
    return array.filter(RegExp.prototype.test, new RegExp([...string].join('.*'), 'i'));
}

var array = ['John Smith', 'Adam Applebaum', 'Steve Wright'];

console.log(filter(array, "jo"));
console.log(filter(array, "sm"));
console.log(filter(array, "josm"));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: awesome thanks, I had to modify a bit to make work for my case but the regex pattern was perfect

Answer (score 0):

`@Nina Scholz` example is great, but actually I would go a bit different way, as regexp `s.*m.*i.*t.*h` may give a bit inaccurate results.

e.g.

Searched: **sh** Results: **John Smith**
Searched: **st** Results: **John Smith**
Searched: **ji** Results: **John Smith**

Actually any letter from first name and any from last name, and in this case results are inaccurate.

I would rather go with regexp `.*SEARCH_PHRASE.*` or to be more exact `.*smi.*`
But this is personal opinion :) just wanted to show the differences.

Final form would be some kind of this:

```js
function buildPattern(str) {
    const arr = [...str];

    // as first item
    arr.splice(0, 0, '.*');

    // as last item
    arr.splice(arr.length, 0, '.*');

    return new RegExp(arr.join(''), 'i');
}

function filter(array, string) {
    return array.filter(RegExp.prototype.test, buildPattern(string));
}

const array = ['John Smith', 'Adam Applebaum', 'Steve Wright'];

console.log(filter(array, "jo"));
console.log(filter(array, "sm"));
console.log(filter(array, "josm"));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```